# How to convert image url to XFile in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm facing a problem from the server I'm getting the image url data as a string. I need to save all these urls in the XFile format list. Tell me how can I convert the image url to XFile format?

**I get**

[image]

Comment: you mean you want to download images from network links, to local device then use them with their own paths in XFile ?

Comment: Yes. I am getting an image url from the web and this image needs to be converted to XFile format.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
static Future<XFile> getImageXFileByUrl(String url) async {
    var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url);
    XFile result = await XFile(file.path);
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can try this code if you also need the mime type or actual file extension,

Need 2 packages [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) and [mime](https://pub.dev/packages/mime).

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' show get;

  Future<XFile> getImageXFileByUrl(String url) async {
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;
    String fileName = "image${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}";
    File fileWrite = new File("$tempPath/$fileName");
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    final response = await get(uri);
    fileWrite.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);
    final mimeType = lookupMimeType("$tempPath/$fileName", headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8]);
    final type = mimeType.split("/");
    final file = XFile("$tempPath/$fileName", mimeType: mimeType);
    return file;
  }
```

headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8] was found on the mime readme file.

[image]